# Excavator badge incorrectly claims to be associated with an "orphan wiki" post

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-wiki, edit-badges

I recieved the Excavator Badge on Gaming.SE for an edit I made to the [starcraft-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/starcraft-2/info) tag wiki. However, [the badge page](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/badges/223/excavator?userid=481) instead lists it as being on an "orphan wiki" post:

[image: screenshot]

This is a bug, although I'm not sure if the bug is how the badge is displayed, or just the fact that I was awarded the badge for a tag wiki edit.

*Edit:* The notification just popped up again (I think the badge was being re-awarded from Waffles' debugging), notice the lack of a title:

[image]

Comment: There are [quite some such "orphan wiki" badges](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/badges/223/excavator).

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure if tag wiki's should be counted for this type of badge.  Tag wikis already have a badge associated with the first edit, but editing an old wiki isn't as valuable as editing an old post IMHO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The excavator badge goes to first edit that happens 6 months or more after the previous edit/create, provided:

1. It is not your post
2. It is a question or answer (not a wiki)
3. It is not deleted

I had a few bugs with the definition initially that caused this, the invalid badges will be revoked shortly.